# Running x86 Windows app on a Raspberry Pi 3B

Tags: kernel, windows, memory, qemu

I followed this guide to install QEMU in a chroot and I'm able to execute x86 Linux binaries: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51895452/qemu-debian-x86-on-raspberrypi

Next, I tried installing WINE and Xvfb. However, running Xvfb gives a single error:

```
Bus error
```

Checking dmesg, I find the following error every time Bus error happens:

```
[  374.559845] Unhandled prefetch abort: unknown 1 (0x001) at 0x604e15a6
```

I'm suspecting this error is due to some sort of memory setting on the host kernel. Is there anything else I need to enable?

As for extra context: the application itself is a Windows app built with Delphi. It takes several images, processes them, and writes some files out. It can be run in batch mode, but it still needs a window to draw to, and I need to manually configure it when installing it for the first time, so I'll need something like x11vnc to access the app the first time.

EDIT: The error also happens when running Wine with no X server - I thought I may be able to run X on the "host" and the app writing to an X socket.

Answer (score 2):

I have run some Delphi Win32 Apps on a Pi using Exagear Desktop and Wine. In some of them I couldn't get the sound working (AFAIK it depends on the exact VCL/CLX sound components the authors have used). The problem is that Exagear Desktop is discontinued and not sold anymore, so if you don't have it you won't get it now.

AFAIK the most prominent option now is to use [`qemu-static`+`winelib`](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=226376), unfortunately, I don't know much about it. The pre-build image seems to be discontinued as well, but the approach itself is proved to work.

Answer (score 0):

Raspberry Pi use ARM-type processors and in general you should understand that x86 and arm instructions are have a lot of architecture differences. ARM is RISC and x86 is CISC architectures so there could be some race conditions due to another way of parallelization of instructions as well as memory protection and management. From your input the app is built with Delphi so it better to look for way compile it to ARM based linux (maybe Android platform) console app or similar then try to run it.