# Install Pytorch to RPi (x86? arm?)

Tags: python-3, raspberry-pi-os

I recently study about running some Deep Learning codes on RPis(Rpi 3) so I tried to install Pytorch 1.4.0 on them.

However It is quite tough job to do as you may know.

I'm so sick of installing Pytorch on the Raspberry Pi and confronting a number of errors, so I'm here to ask you some questions.

So my question is,

1. I heard that the main reason that makes hard to install packages is because RPi is based on ARM architecture. Is this true?
2. If the first question is true, using x86 board like Latte Panda, Udoo board can solve the problem?

The questions may seem stupid, but please understand.. I'm totally new to RPi. Thank you in advance!

Comment: It is equally impossible to install Pi  programs on Windows!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running x86 Windows app on a Raspberry Pi 3B](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/109648/running-x86-windows-app-on-a-raspberry-pi-3b)

Comment: @Dmitry Grigoryv It's similar but I'm rather trying to install Python's libraries originally desinged to be run in Window env than run Window's app. Anyway thanks for your answer! That was also helpful.

Comment: @2nebin In that case it's not about CPU architecture, so x86 boards won't be of any help unless you'll actually run Windows on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is not fully incorrect but it's not correct either!

Yes the Pi is ARM but a lot of repositories for programs are compiled C or C++ and built ready by the distribution maintainers. Other code (e.g.PHP) does not care what the chipset is and then more source is compiled by users on their own machine. Instructions for building from source is [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch#from-source)

As for the second part, if you dig into the install routines you will see the list of requirements for the provided program is stored [here](https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html) and a quick read will show these are flagged as being 64bit X86 (Intel / AMD) so yes it is possible one of the other board mentioned will fix your issue IF they meet minimal specs.